# How to show LinearLayout after complete ListView in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to show LinearLayout after complete ListView is displayed. My code shows ListView and fixed LinearLayout at bottom. I don’t want LinearLayout fixed at bottom.

**What I want is:** if my ListView has 20 items, user scroll to view all items and see LinearLayout at the end of ListView items.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:textSize="14dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:text="Your Email:"
            android:textSize="12dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNew"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`addFooterView(View)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) for this.

> Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the
>   list. If addFooterView is called more than once, the views will appear
>   in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take
>   focus if they want.
>
> **Parameters**
>   -     *v* The view to add.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a ListView footer.

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Your `footer_layout` could be whatever you want, for example a `LinearLayout`. You have to do this **AFTER** you set the `Adapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a footer view to your listView, So your layout look like this.

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:footerDividersEnabled="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

footer.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="10dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:textSize="14dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="Your Email:"
        android:textSize="12dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/newEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonNew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater)    ActivityContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer  ayout, null, false);
ListView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Thats it.